# How to generate repetitions in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data in Excel:

```
start date  end date    number of repetition
 0             515            423
 0             484            982
 0             456           5,012
 0             425           1,063
 0             395           2,148
```

I need to generate for example 423 repetitions of corresponding start date and end date in a column like this:

```
0
515
0
515
...
```

And then the rest of the repetitions start after that in the same column..

Comment: I think you will have to use vbscript. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Here is the single item version of this.  You may be able to modify it to repeat two items.  If not, you could get it in two steps, repeating each label the number of times and then using a second formula to alternate the rows and go down a column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805665/how-to-create-a-dynamic-table-in-excel/30808646#30808646

Comment: @ByronWall This is exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to edit it to repeat two items...

Comment: I don't either and I wrote the first one!  Seriously, you might want to consider VBA or a multi step process.  That other answer could be modified to work here, but this is much more easily handled with VBA.

Comment: @ByronWall Scott helped me to change your function for my problem but my data is changed it doesn't work for this data! He doesn't answer me anymore, can you please take a look at it to see whether you can help me or not? Thanks

Comment: Ask a new question with a specific scope and expected input/output.  Add a link to this question to give context.  Note you still need to require enough detail for the question to stand on its own.  By all accounts, @Scott, has provided a solid answer to your original question.  It's unreasonable to expect him to update it since you changed your data 2 days after his answer.  It would also be polite to accept his answer since it resolves the original question.  In general a non response from a high rep user indicates they have moved on from the question (or are on vacation, I guess).

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to adapt
[Byron Wall](https://superuser.com/users/393632/byron-wall)’s answer
to [How to create a dynamic table in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30805665/1672723) (on Stack Overflow)
to alternate between the two columns:

- `E2` → `=A2`
- `E3` → `=B2`
- `E4` → `=IF(`
      `INDEX(C$2:C$99, MATCH(E2,A$2:A$99), 1) > COUNTIF(E$2:E2, E2),`
      `E2,`
      `INDEX(A$2:A$99, MATCH(E2,A$2:A$99)+1, 1))`
- `E5` → `=IF(`
      `INDEX(C$2:$C99, MATCH(E2,A$2:A$99), 1) > COUNTIF(E$2:E2, E2),`
      `E3,`
      `INDEX(B$2:B$99, MATCH(E2,A$2:A$99)+1, 1))`

Then select `E4` and `E5` together and drag down. 
Of course you should replace `99` with the last row number of your source data
(or something higher).

For testing/demonstration purposes, I

- changed the repetition counts to something manageable,
  so I wouldn’t have to drag down to Row 828 (2×413+2)
  just to see `32` (`A3`) for the first time,
- changed the end dates `B3:B6`,
  so it would be obvious that `B3`, `B4`, `B5`, and `B6` were being displayed
  opposite `A3`, `A4`, `A5`, and `A6` (and not `B2` over and over again),
- *for display purposes only,* split Column `E` into two pieces,
  so the image could be 20 rows high rather than 38.

  [image]

This allows the date ranges to overlap, as above,

> or like this:                  or to be non-overlapping, like this:
>
> ```
> start date  end date                                      start date  end date
>      0         15                                              1         10
>     10         25                                             11         20
>     20         35                                             21         30
>     30         45                                             31         40
>     40         55                                             41         50
> ```

But it does not allow `A` values to have occurred on previous rows as `B` values

> like this:                        or like this:
>
> ```
> start date  end date                                      start date  end date
>      1          8                                              1         15
>      8         15                                              8         22
>     15         22                                             15         29
>     22         29                                             22         36
>     29         36                                             29         43
> ```

(i.e., the ranges must not be contiguous). 
If you need to handle data like that, change `E4` and `E5` to:

- `E4` → `=IF(`
      `INDEX(C$2:C$99, MATCH(E2,A$2:A$99), 1) >`
                `SUMPRODUCT(--(E$2:E2 = E2), --(MOD(ROW(E$2:E2),2)=0)),`
      `E2,`
      `INDEX(A$2:A$99, MATCH(E2,A$2:A$99)+1, 1))`
- `E5` → `=IF(`
      `INDEX(C$2:C$99, MATCH(E2,A$2:A$99), 1) >`
                `SUMPRODUCT(--(E$2:E2 = E2), --(MOD(ROW(E$2:E2),2)=0)),`
      `E3,`
      `INDEX(B$2:B$99, MATCH(E2,A$2:A$99)+1, 1))`

I have formatted the start dates to be blue and the end dates to be yellow,
for clarity:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My data has been changed and all the start points are 0 now. On this new data it doesn't work...Please see the question for the new data..Thanks

Comment: Nice adaptation of the original formula.  Always crazy how far these things can be extended if you have the patience.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but you have to manually adjust for each line. You can autofill this formula down however many times you need, it will start returning blank when it's done enough repetitions. To do the first row (1,516) you use:

```
=IF(ROW()<=C$2*2+1,IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),A$2,B$2),"")
```

Adjusting for the next row looks like:

```
=IF(ROW()<=C$3*2+1,IF(ISEVEN(ROW()),A$3,B$3),"")
```